# My shell script for starting NGiNX is not working

Tags: shell, ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-12.04

I found this small shell script in a book... NGiNX works it just this script that just does not work. Because every time I do /etc/init.d/nginx start (that is where the file is) it sends me this message: Usage: /etc/init.d/nginx {start|stop|restart|reload}

For testing purposes I added a echo "$1" and it sends me -e when I do: /etc/init.d/nginx start Or anything else...

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

```
#! /bin/sh
# Author: Ryan Norbauer http://norbauerinc.com
# Modified: Geoffrey Grosenbach http://topfunky.com
# Modified: Clement NEDELCU
# Reproduced with express authorization from its contributors
set –e
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DESC="nginx daemon"
NAME=nginx
DAEMON=/usr/local/nginx/sbin/$NAME
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME
# If the daemon file is not found, terminate the script.
test -x $DAEMON || exit 0
echo "0"
d_start() {
$DAEMON || echo -n " already running"
}

d_stop() {
$DAEMON –s quit || echo -n " not running"
}

d_reload() {
$DAEMON –s reload || echo -n " could not reload"
}
echo "$1"
case "$1" in
    start)
            echo -n "Starting $DESC: $NAME"
            d_start
            echo "."
    ;;
    stop)
            echo -n "Stopping $DESC: $NAME"
            d_stop
            echo "."
    ;;
    reload)
            echo -n "Reloading $DESC configuration..."
            d_reload
            echo "reloaded."
    ;;
    restart)
            echo -n "Restarting $DESC: $NAME"
            d_stop
            # Sleep for two seconds before starting again, this should give the
            # Nginx daemon some time to perform a graceful stop.
            sleep 2
            d_start
            echo "."
            ;;
    *)
            echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|restart|reload}" >&2
            exit 3
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: What shell are you using? `sh --version`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set –e` is setting the list of arguments to the script to `–e`. Remove that line and the script will work.

**Edit:** The script posted contains `set –e` (that is EN DASH + e) as opposed to `set -e` (ASCII hyphen/minus sign + e). This caused `sh` to override the first argument passed with `–e` instead of setting the `-e` option in the shell. Replacing `–` with `-` should fix the problem.

Comment: To be honest, I doubt it will. If the particular shell can't eat `set -e`, it certainly shouldn't support bashisms like `echo -n`.

Comment: Tried it on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine (where `/bin/sh` -> `/bin/dash` and that was the fix.

Comment: Weird. My `dash` has no problem with `set -e`…

Comment: `dash` might behave differently when called as `/bin/sh`. Also, `echo -n` might be supported by executing `/bin/echo` instead of having `echo` as a builtin.

Comment: I tried exactly that (as I have dash at `/bin/sh` as well)… and `set -e` is POSIX.

Comment: It turns out that the script he posted contains "–e" (EN DASH e) as opposed to "-e" (hyphen e). Swapping the characters fixes the problem.

Comment: It was the dash... For some reason... Thanks guys.

Comment: nice job of debugging! Given how difficult it would be to see the extra 2 pixels on a hyphen that turn it into an en-dash, AND that the source of so much code, is like this question, something found in html , it's surprising this doesn't turn up as a problem more often. Good luck to all.